# mysql - cancel default database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After I choose default DB with -

`USE testDB`

How can I cancel it and go back to work with no default DB ?

I use  - `MYSQL WORKBENCH version 5.4.14`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It doesn't make sense to me. You will have to prefix every table with a database name.

Comment: I though so ... so you say there is no such command ?

Comment: No, there isn't. At least none that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The `USE schema` command is a convenience command to avoid having to explicitly qualify all identifiers that belong to a gvien schema. More informations [in the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/use.html).

*A side note: I strongly recommend to always use the [latest MySQL Workbench version](http://mysqlworkbench.org/). We are constantly fixing bugs and add new cool fetaures.*